# Rhino load() function available in JavaScript provided by javax.script?

Tags: javascript, load, rhino, javax.script

Some JavaScript files that have been developed for Rhino's shell use load() to load additional JavaScript files. I'm attempting to embed functionality from one of these Rhino JavaScript files using javax.script. Unfortunately, the load() function is not implemented by javax.script's JavaScript. When attempting to eval() a script containing load(), the following error occurs:

```
com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine:-1:in `eval': javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "load" is  not defined.
```

Does javax.script provide a for the load() function when evaluating a JavaScript file from within a Java program (not from a shell)?

Comment: You may have an easier time embedding upstream Rhino, rather than attempting to use the version that comes with the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The load function is very old. In the lastest RC (RC3) of Rhino there is a [commonJS module](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.0) loader implementation.

You will have to switch to an embedded version of Rhino. Once you have created a script context you can install the require function.

So if you loaded a file `'./math.js'` would become `var math = require('math');`. After you created your module provider with the URI of the module.