# How do I load a local file from rhino embedded in a vendor product?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

My question is pretty similar to [How can I load a local file from embedded Rhino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461648/how-can-i-load-a-local-file-from-embedded-rhino).

Most of the suggestions I've have read suggested modifying java code, but I'm using Rhino that's embedded in vendor software (both Shibboleth and NetIQ IDM), so I don't have access to context in which Rhino exists (or the code that creates it), only the script engine that's been spawned in that context.

[Corderer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26286/coderer) suggested doing something like...

`eval("" + Packages.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(
  new java.io.File("/the/local/root", "script.js");
));`

...which works!  Like Corderer, though, I was hoping for a less ugly solution (maybe actually being able to use load()).  Is `eval()` the best / easiest option to do this?

Liam

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but from what I understand, you just want to read a file on disk from within JavaScript. If so, you can do this:

```
var fileObj = new java.io.File("/the/local/root/somefile.txt");
```

This will basically give you access to a Java file object, which then you can manipulate to your heart's content. See the [documentation for the java.io.File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to see what methods are available.

**Edit**: After further review of the question, it seems that you want to load a JavaScript source file from within JavaScript. If so, then you can use Rhino's built-in [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell#load.28.5Bfilename.2C_....5D.29) command like so:

```
load("/the/local/root/script.js");
```

Comment: load() only works from the rhino shell, not when you're running in embedded mode.

Comment: @uglycat5 Can you point to any reference to back that statement? I've worked on a product that shipped with Rhinojs embedded and `load` worked fine for us.

Comment: [How can I load a local file from embedded Rhino?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461648/how-can-i-load-a-local-file-from-embedded-rhino); [Rhino load() function available in JavaScript provided by javax.script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539624/rhino-load-function-available-in-javascript-provided-by-javax-script?rq=1); [Including a JavaScript file during Rhino eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357334/including-a-javascript-file-during-rhino-eval)

Comment: I'm using Rhino 1.7r4.  The JS is invoked by rhino embedded in Shibboleth.  The error returned is `javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "load" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#10) in <Unknown Source> at line number 10`

Answer (score 0):

Years later, here's my take:
Create a `Global` object that has the missing `load` function.

```
g = new Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global(Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext());
this.load = g.load;
```

The `g` variable now holds the `global` object used in Rhino scripts.